# How to get 2 columns in ListView using SimpleCursor Adapter in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I am using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to populate my listview with **one column**, but I have to change it and populate my listview with **2 columns**.

Now my code looks like this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter SimpleCursorAdapter;
ListView listWords = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listWords);
wordsRepo wordsRepo = new wordsRepo(this);
TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

private void showWords()
{
    Cursor cursor = wordsRepo.getword();

    if (cursor == null)
    {
        textview.setText("Error");
        return;
    }
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
    {
        textview.setText("No Words.");
        return;
    }

    String[] from = new String[] {word.KEY_EN_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

    SimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,from,to,0);
    listCategories.setAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter);
}
```

And listview displays only value of `word.KEY_EN_NAME`, but now I want to display 2 columns : `word.KEY_EN_NAME` , and `word.KEY_ES_NAME`.

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: so your `from` and `to` arrays should have two items: two column names and two view ids

Comment: better use recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager is very easy

Comment: @psking I tried to do like: `String[] from = new String[] {word.KEY_EN_NAME, word.KEY_ES_NAME};` but what should I put inside `to` ?? I didn't create my own listview layout.

Comment: so use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` and see what text views it has, if `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` is not what you need you have to create your own xml layout file